# Black screen after installing Nvidia drivers on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, xorg, drivers, nvidia

I have installed latest Debian Stretch on my MSI laptop and I want to install Nvidia proprietary drivers for my GTX 1060 graphics card.

I followed this guide on Debian's wiki: https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers.

Here are the steps I followed on my fresh install:

First I added stretch-backports and 'contrib non-free' postfix. My /etc/apt/sources.list dump:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.7.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190123-19:36]/ stretch main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.7.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190123-19:36]/ stretch main

deb http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main

# stretch-backports
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then I ran the followings as root:

```
$ dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install build-essential
$ apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//')
$ apt-get -t stretch-backports install nvidia-driver
```

I rebooted the system but on boot where gnome should have started I see a black screen without a cursor. I do have access to other terminals. Here is my Xorg.0.log:

```
[    23.138] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-823.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
[    23.140] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[    23.140] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    23.140] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    23.140] Current Operating System: Linux zion 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64
[    23.140] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64 root=UUID=79569e63-703c-4939-ae49-32f4997c9c72 ro quiet
[    23.140] Build Date: 03 November 2018  03:09:11AM
[    23.140] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[    23.140] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    23.140]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    23.140] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    23.140] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Feb 13 20:06:40 2019
[    23.143] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    23.145] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    23.145] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    23.145] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    23.145] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    23.146] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    23.146] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    23.146] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    23.146] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    23.146] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    23.148] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    23.148]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.152] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    23.152] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    23.152] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    23.152] (II) Loader magic: 0x555783fdbe00
[    23.152] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    23.152]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    23.152]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    23.152]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    23.152]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    23.154] (++) using VT number 1

[    23.159] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2
[    23.159] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    23.161] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 0
[    23.165] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:3e9b:1462:1223 rev 0, Mem @ 0xa2000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    23.165] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:1c20:1462:1223 rev 161, Mem @ 0xa3000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    23.165] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    23.167] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[    23.215] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    23.215]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.215]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    23.215] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  390.87  Tue Aug 21 16:10:56 PDT 2018
[    23.216] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card0
[    23.216]    loading driver: nvidia
[    23.216] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    23.216] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    23.216] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[    23.216] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[    23.216] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    23.216] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 5
[    23.216] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    23.216] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    23.216] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    23.221] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    23.221]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.221]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.221] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    23.221] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    23.223] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.223]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.13
[    23.223]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.223]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.223] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    23.223] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    23.223] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    23.223] (II) Unloading nv
[    23.223] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    23.223] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    23.223] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    23.224] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.224]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.19.2
[    23.224]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.224]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.224] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    23.224] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    23.224] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.224]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    23.224]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.224]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.224] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    23.224] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    23.225] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.225]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 2.3.4
[    23.225]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.225]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.225] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  390.87  Tue Aug 21 15:44:49 PDT 2018
[    23.225] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    23.225] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Sep 20 00:31:06 2016 -0400
[    23.225] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    23.225]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    23.225]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    23.226]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    23.226]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    23.226]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    23.226]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    23.226]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    23.226]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    23.226]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    23.226]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    23.226]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    23.226]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    23.226]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    23.226] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    23.226] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    23.226] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    23.226] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:0
[    23.226] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -2
[    23.226] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    23.226] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    23.226] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    23.226] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    23.227] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.227]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    23.227]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    23.227] (**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 0@0:2:0
[    23.227] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
[    23.227] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    23.227] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    23.227] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    23.227] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    23.227] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    23.227] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[    23.227] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    23.227] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    23.227] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: EFI VGA (video memory: 1920kB)
[    23.227] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[    23.227] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[    23.227] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 800x600 (pitch 800)
[    23.227] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 48.0 MHz, 46.9 kHz, 75.1 Hz
[    23.227] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0   48.00  800 832 928 1024  600 604 608 624 -hsync -vsync -csync (46.9 kHz b)
[    23.227] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    23.227] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    23.227] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    23.227] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    23.228] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.228]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.228]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    23.228] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[    23.228] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    23.228] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    23.228] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    23.228] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.228]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.1.0
[    23.228]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    23.228] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    23.228] (II) Unloading vesa
[    23.228] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    23.228] (II) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument (Screen blanking not supported by kernel - disabling)
[    23.230] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[    23.231] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[    23.231] (==) RandR enabled
[    23.233] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    23.233] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[    23.283] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event5)
[    23.283] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    23.283] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    23.283] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    23.284] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.284]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.23.0
[    23.284]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    23.284]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    23.284] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    23.285] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 22 paused 0
[    23.285] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    23.285] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    23.285] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.285] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.285] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[    23.285] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input6/event5"
[    23.285] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    23.285] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.285] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.285] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.285] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[    23.286] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event2)
[    23.286] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.286] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.286] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[    23.286] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    23.286] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    23.286] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 25 paused 0
[    23.286] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    23.286] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    23.286] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.286] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.286] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    23.286] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input5/event4"
[    23.286] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    23.286] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.286] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.287] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.287] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    23.287] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event3)
[    23.287] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    23.287] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    23.287] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 26 paused 0
[    23.287] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    23.287] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    23.287] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.287] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.287] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    23.287] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input4/event3"
[    23.287] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    23.287] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.287] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.287] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.287] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    23.288] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Headphone (/dev/input/event9)
[    23.288] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.288] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.288] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[    23.288] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.288] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.288] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[    23.288] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    23.288] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    23.288] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 27 paused 0
[    23.289] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    23.289] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    23.289] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.289] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.289] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[    23.289] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/event0"
[    23.289] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    23.289] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.289] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.289] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.289] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[    23.289] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event1)
[    23.289] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[    23.289] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    23.290] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 28 paused 0
[    23.290] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    23.290] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    23.290] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.290] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    23.290] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is a touchpad
[    23.290] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input2/event1"
[    23.290] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 10)
[    23.290] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    23.290] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    23.290] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    23.290] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    23.290] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    23.290] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is a touchpad
[    23.290] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    23.290] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.290] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.290] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event6)
[    23.291] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.291] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.291] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MSI WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event7)
[    23.291] (**) MSI WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    23.291] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MSI WMI hotkeys'
[    23.291] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event7 13:71 fd 29 paused 0
[    23.291] (**) MSI WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[    23.291] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    23.291] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.291] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.291] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[    23.291] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input8/event7"
[    23.291] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MSI WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    23.291] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.291] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.292] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.292] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[    36.511] (**) Option "fd" "22"
[    36.511] (**) Option "fd" "25"
[    36.511] (**) Option "fd" "26"
[    36.512] (**) Option "fd" "27"
[    36.512] (**) Option "fd" "28"
[    36.512] (**) Option "fd" "29"
[    36.515] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
[    36.515] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
[    36.515] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
[    36.515] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
[    36.515] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
[    36.515] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
[    55.096] (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:64
[    55.097] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    55.097] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[    55.120] (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:67
[    55.121] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    55.121] (II) input device 'Sleep Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    55.140] (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:69
[    55.141] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    55.141] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[    55.156] (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:68
[    55.157] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    55.157] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    55.176] (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:65
[    55.177] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    55.177] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event1 is a touchpad
[    55.192] (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:71
[    55.193] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    55.193] (II) input device 'MSI WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[    57.379] (**) Option "fd" "26"
[    57.379] (**) Option "fd" "27"
[    57.379] (**) Option "fd" "25"
[    57.379] (**) Option "fd" "22"
[    57.379] (**) Option "fd" "28"
[    57.380] (**) Option "fd" "29"
[    57.383] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
[    57.383] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
[    57.383] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
[    57.383] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
[    57.383] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
[    57.383] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
```

And related messages from dmesg:

```
.
.
[   20.051031] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   20.051034] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   20.051035] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   20.058235] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 248
[   20.058370] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[   20.058443] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[   20.058489] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.87  Tue Aug 21 12:33:05 PDT 2018 (using threaded interrupts)
[   20.069920] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  390.87  Tue Aug 21 16:16:14 PDT 2018
[   20.075365] [drm] Initialized
[   20.079182] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:18/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input3
[   20.079488] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[   20.079844] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input4
[   20.079848] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[   20.079889] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input5
[   20.079891] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[   20.079937] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input6
[   20.079938] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[   20.087606] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[   20.087913] ACPI: AC Adapter [ADP1] (on-line)
.
.
.
[   22.621804] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   22.622573] alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[   22.622829] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[   23.754442] gnome-session-f[870]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f7cef889e19 sp 00007ffd529ea4e0 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.2200.11[7f7cef5a7000+700000]
[   33.821642] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   33.821643] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   33.821645] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Do you have any idea what may be the problem?

Update: If I wait long enough on black screen, I get a curser.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on Manjaro and it was caused by a problem with ACPI. In order to get my laptop to boot to the desktop, I had to add the following kernel parameter:

```
acpi_rev_override=5
```

After I added this parameter, my system booted fine using the nVidia driver.

Comment: I think I don't have any problem related to ACPI. Nevertheless, I tried it but nothing is changed.

Comment: The only other thing I can see is that the Nouveau driver is loading. In some distros, this has been known to cause issues with the nVidia driver loading. you might want to try disabling it on start by trying this kernel parameter:

modprobe.blacklist=nouveau

If that does not work, I am sorry.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, but also wish to add that you should reconfigure X after that.

Comment: Actually nouveau is blacklisted. When I do apt-get install nvidia-driver nouveau is added to blacklist and I can confirm that nouveau is not loaded with my lsmod output.